# Using ng-change in AngularJS with "Controller As" syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to avoid using $scope in my controller function, instead opting to use

```
var viewModel = this;
```

with "controller as" viewModel syntax. 
My problem is that I need to use ng-change to call a function in my controller but while I am able to access data from a service, I am unable to call functions.

```
//Controller
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('GeneralSettingsController', GeneralSettingsController);

GeneralSettingsController.$inject = ['SimulationService'];
function GeneralSettingsController(SimulationService) {
    var viewModel = this;
    viewModel.SimulationService = SimulationService;
    viewModel.setSimulationPeriod = setSimulationPeriod;

    function setSimulationPeriod() {
        console.log("Entered local setSimulationPeriod");
        viewModel.SimulationService.setSimulationPeriod();
    }
}
})();
```

The controller is being instantiated in a directive that defines the controller and controllerAs: 'viewModel'

My html looks like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="startyear" name="startyear" placeholder="start year"
                       autocomplete="off" value="2017" maxlength="4"
                       ng-model="viewModel.SimulationService.data.simulationPeriodStart" ng-change="viewModel.setSimulationPeriod">
</div>
```

I was able to call things fine when I used $scope instead of referencing the controller however I feel this is not ideal. I was hoping there is a way of calling a function with ng-change that still uses viewModel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jusopi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1121919/jusopi) was right. My controller was not wired up correctly. The problem was that I had another controller active at a higher scope which was also set to controllerAs: viewModel. This caused me to reference the wrong controller where the function did not exist. Once I gave this controller a unique name everything went smoothly which is why it worked for $scope.

Answer (score 1):

### angular expressions

You're not calling the function. Instead try:

```
 <input ng-change="viewModel.setSimulationPeriod()">
```

Note the () at the end of your function.  Ng-change, like most other angular directives use expressions, meaning they're actually trying to execute a subset of JavaScript. In this case when you just passed a reference to your vm's function, it simply evaluated it rather than executing it.

### order of assignment

Also, you've defined the viewModel function *before* you've defined the function you're setting it to. Move the function declaration above the part of your code where you assign it to your viewModel.

**instead of this**

```
viewModel.setSimulationPeriod = setSimulationPeriod;

function setSimulationPeriod() {
    console.log("Entered local setSimulationPeriod");
    viewModel.SimulationService.setSimulationPeriod();
}
```

**reorder it like this**

```
function setSimulationPeriod() {
    console.log("Entered local setSimulationPeriod");
    viewModel.SimulationService.setSimulationPeriod();
}

viewModel.setSimulationPeriod = setSimulationPeriod;
```

Comment: I have made your suggested change, unfortunately this still does not call the function.

Comment: You've also set the viewModel's function to an undefined value before defining your function.  Move the function declaration up in your file, then set it to your viewModel

Comment: I moved the function above         
viewModel.setSimulationPeriod = setSimulationPeriod;

however this still doesn't work.

Comment: Set a read only value on your viewModel and then bind to it. Let's make sure you are actually getting your viewModel wired up.

Comment: FYI, functions in JS are hoisted so the declaration order shouldn't matter

Comment: I believe I have already done this. I can call 
{{viewModel.SimulationService.data.simulationPeriodStart}}
for example and it evaluates to whatever is in the input field.

Comment: Okay. Seems I haven't wired the controller up correctly. I added
        viewModel.foo = "bar";
to my controller and {{viewModel.foo}} does not evaluate.

Comment: On a side note. Phil is correct, JS functions are hoisted so there is no need to reorder the code. Secondly you _can_ pass directives references to a function and they will execute, so 
`ng-change="viewModel.setSimulationPeriod"`
works fine as well.

Comment: Regarding passing a function as a reference rather than executing it, at least in NG 1.3.14, your statement is incorrect according to my test here - http://codepen.io/jusopi/pen/bEjyQq

Comment: Yep, you are right again. I retested it just using references and you do indeed need the curved brackets.