# Angular: $scope works but "controller as" does not fire ng-change event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a controller as follows:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('vweb')
    .controller('ProfilesController', ProfilesController);

  /** @ngInject */
  function ProfilesController(profileService, $scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.searchTerm = '';
    vm.profileService = profileService;

    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded',
      function () {
        vm.searchProfiles();
      });

    vm.searchProfiles = function() {
      alert("term: " + vm.searchTerm);
      profileService.searchProfiles(vm.searchTerm)
        .then(function (profiles) {
          alert("Here's my profiles " + angular.toJson(profiles));
        });
    }

  }
})();
```

Along with an input field (search term):

```
<input type="text" class="search-query form-control" placeholder="Search" 
ng-model="controller.searchTerm" ng-change="controller.searchProfiles()"/>
```

And the start of the profiles.html page is: `<div class="container" ng-controller="ProfilesController as controller">`

When using this approach, the change event on the input field does not fire in the controller. But changing from 'controller as' style to `$scope` works fine.

I'm using the ui-router framework rather than ng-route. (The yeoman generator I used to start chose this for me).

**Question:**

I just started angular in the last few days, but read 'controller as' is easier to test. How can I make this work with 'controller as' style?

Comment: Try removing $scope entirely and use vm instead- vm.$on

Not 100% this will work but it's worth a shot.

Comment: what router are you using for this? ui-router or ng-router?

Comment: Can you show us how you declare the controllerAs value?

Comment: @S.Buda I tried vm.on before raising the question. It didn't work. There's other ways to get the same functionality I guess, though.

Comment: @Subash I'm using ui-router. I suspected possibly router related, but just tried changing to ng-route - same issue. So I think probably not now.

Comment: @Kraken, do you mean `<div class="container" ng-controller="ProfilesController as controller">` as shown in the question?

Comment: Does it makes a difference if you use `ng-change="controller.searchProfiles()"` (note the parentheses at the end)?

Comment: @medievalgeek I tried both of these. Docs all seem to show parentheses at the end.

Comment: That's odd; it should work with the parentheses.  Do you have more than one controller on the page?  If so, check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35143675/using-ng-change-in-angularjs-with-controller-as-syntax).

Comment: I have one ui-view div, and a state that routes to the login controller+page combination. So no, I don't think so.

Comment: You're making a call to searchProfiles in your `$scope.$on` function before it is defined, which is causing the rest of the code to not load.

Comment: @EricWei Yes it was that - thank you! If you care to post answer I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making a call to searchProfiles in your `$scope.$on` function before it is defined, which is causing the rest of the code to not load.

Answer (score 1):

According to [`ng-change`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange). You should use:

```
ng-change="controller.searchProfiles()"
```

instead of:

```
ng-change="controller.searchProfiles"
```